# Unit test form submission with data using react testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a react component with a form. I want to unit test (using jest and RTL) if form gets submitted with correct data. Here are my component and unit test method:

**Component:**

```
class AddDeviceModal extends Component {
  handleOnSave(event) {
    const { deviceName } = event.target;
    const formData = {
      deviceName: deviceName.value,
    };
    this.props.onSave(formData);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleOnSave}>
        <Form.Label>Device Name</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control name="deviceName" placeholder="Device Name" required />
        <Button type="submit">Save Device</Button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

**Unit Test:**

```
it("Test form submit and validation", () => {
  const handleSave = jest.fn();
  const props = {
    onSave: handleSave,
  };
  render(<AddDeviceModal {...props} />);
  const deviceNameInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText(/device name/i);
  fireEvent.change(deviceNameInput, { target: { value: "AP VII C2230" } });
  fireEvent.click(getByText(/save device/i));
});
```

However, in `handleOnSave()`, I get error as `deviceName` is `undefined`. For some reason, it is not able to get the textbox value from `event.target`. Am I doing something wrong in above code? Needed help in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem you have it with trying to access the input directly from `event.target`. You should access it from `event.target.elements` instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements.

```
function handleOnSave(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { deviceName } = event.target.elements;
  const formData = {
    deviceName: deviceName.value
  };

  // this will log the correct formData even in tests now
  console.log(formData);
  this.props.onSave(formData);
}
```

And here is your test:

```
it("Test form submit and validation", () => {
  const { getByPlaceholderText, getByText } = render(<App />);
  const deviceNameInput = getByPlaceholderText(/device name/i);

  fireEvent.change(deviceNameInput, { target: { value: "AP VII C2230" } });
  fireEvent.click(getByText(/Save Device/i));
});
```

I created a codesandbox where you can see this in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-submit-react-testing-library-45pt8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: GTK. What's the difference though when running `test`? Why we can't just use the `.` with the `input` `id` as we would in the browser?

Comment: How is this test adding any value without any `expect` statement? It's just simply rendering the App component and getting the button element and firing a click event. It is not testing if the `onSubmit` is called or not.

Answer (score 0):

I used `jest` and `react-testing-library`.

I personally don't like the idea of changing the Form component code by passing a mock or spy function just for testing purpose.

For my form, I come up with this idea (`find the code samples and full answer` [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77035248/13607767)) -

- basically I created `handleOnSubmitMock` function, and then assigned it to `screen.getByRole("form", { name: "signup-form" }).onsubmit` GlobalEventHandler. (Not passing the mock function to the Form)
- then I checked if `expect(handleOnSubmitMock).toHaveBeenCalled()` or `expect(handleOnSubmitMock).not.toHaveBeenCalled()` passes.

You should be able to modify the code for your need from the descriptive code samples in the [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77035248/13607767), and it should work. The goal is to  -

- render the `Form` component.
- get the necessary elements.
- fire the button click event.
- expect `onSubmit` handler to be either called or not called depending on the test conditions.